# Convex Hull compare options

Tags: mesh

If I transform triangles into quads, options Compare UV, VCol, Sharp... trying to preserve the original structure of edges or materials (as far as I understand). Below is an example of work Compare options:
[image]
But I can not achieve any change in mesh with options Compare UV, VCol, Sharp... with the instrument Convex Hull.

Explain, please, what do these options in the context of the Convex Hull tool (preferably with pictures)